# Getting Access Token but not allowed to sign in

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, gmsmapview

So a buddy of mine is helping me test my app out. However, after he gets the allow or deny screen, it doesn't let him to actually sign into the app even though we are getting an access code. The following errors show up in the run dialog when I ran the app on his Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge:

```
09/30 20:25:23: Launching MainActivity
$ adb push C:\Users\James Singleton\AndroidStudioProjects\ChffrAPI\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 1082 on device samsung-sm_g925t-1115fb9dddda2805
E/Zygote: v2
I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1 ver=11
W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0013
E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10248
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi 
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi rsrc of package com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi-1/lib/arm64
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi, Feature store :{}
I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi rsrc of package com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi rsrc of package com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi rsrc of package com.google.android.gms
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi rsrc of package com.google.android.gms
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000a/n/arm64-v8a
W/nAnnotationIntrospector: Unable to load JDK7 annotation types; will have to skip
I/System.out: Connection Preference: wifi
D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity isFragment :false
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b22bf4b I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7fa3b3f178
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

                  [ 09-30 20:25:36.141  1082: 1182 D/         ]
                  ro.exynos.dss isEnabled: 0
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity
I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity
D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
I/System.out: com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.AuthPreferences@2af7be6
E/AuthApp: ya29.Ci9vAy3YMsGUZcVJ28kRIh5lMQMYhbSUSelWfYABrGmSWkKXKgUhRC_A4KJJcnJtBQ
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@6065402 time:27457508
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{23821be token=android.os.BinderProxy@6065402 {com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity}} show : true
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@6065402 time:27522831
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{23821be token=android.os.BinderProxy@6065402 {com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity}} show : true
```

I am not sure what any of this means. If I take the access token that is given I can use oAuth 2.0 playground and proceed like normal.

Answer (score 0):

So the user was not connected to his preferred connection. His preferred connection was `I/System.out: Connection Preference: wifi` and he was connected to 4G. I added the following to check for it:

```
else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are not connected to your preferred connection." + "\n" +
                            "Please connect to your preferred connection to continue."
                            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```